Ignore / Suppress specific magic number warning in detekt baseline.xml for a Compose function
To ignore magic number in a class, we can do this:
    <ID>MagicNumber:FeatureManager.kt$FeatureManager$30</ID>

Where, FeatureManager is class, and 30 is magic number.
What would happen if this is in compose lets say:
@Composable
fun CustomComposable(){
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        delay(3000) // this needs to be added to baseline
        ...
    }
}

I have tried multiple approaches, but still I am unable to suppress this.
Referencing direct function from file reference:
    <ID>MagicNumber:CustomComposable.kt$CustomComposable$3000</ID>

Referencing direct magic number from file reference:
    <ID>MagicNumber:CustomComposable.kt$3000</ID>

Referencing direct magic number from element (function) reference:
    <ID>MagicNumber:CustomComposable$3000</ID>

This is hit and trial. I know that already, that this is not the way to do it (not mentioned in the docs what to do either)
Only reference to read for Baseline I found is this detekt website

I finally found the solution thanks to a discussion thread reply from detekt discussion board.
To sum it up, instead of:
    <ID>MagicNumber:CustomComposable.kt$CustomComposable$3000</ID>

We should do:
    <ID>MagicNumber:CustomComposable.kt$3000</ID>

Just refer magic number in case of Composable with its file.
We can find the exact signature here: build/reports/detekt/detekt.txt
Example report entry:
MagicNumber - [<anonymous>] at /Users/Documents/androidApp/src/main/java/tech/android/ui/BottomSheet.kt:170:33 - Signature=BottomSheet.kt$0.7f

Suppress format (as per detekt) : <RuleID>:<Codesmell_Signature>
Finally:
<ID>MagicNumber:BottomSheet.kt$0.7f<ID>

This will do for Composables. One caveat is it will ignore other 0.7f occurences too in the file.
PS: Although I tried this earlier (as mentioned in the question) but weird enough it wasn't working.
